# getSelect Question

Tags: collection

Why cant I do the following:

```
            $this->getSelect()
        ->columns(
            array(
                'ordered_qty' => 'COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id)', 
                'invoiced_qty' => new Zend_Db_Expr('( select COUNT(OI.item_id) AS Ct from sales_flat_order_item AS OI WHERE OI.order_id=main_table.entity_id ) AS invoiced_qty')
                            )
                    );
```

The subquery fails with the error, "Cannot determine the field name"

Comment: Well the issue is certainly with the invoiced_qty column because it goes away when I comment it out.

Comment: Ok, so when I log the $attribute variable using Mage::log() I get this:                                                                2013-08-12T20:00:18+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => invoiced_qty
    [1] => Zend_Db_Expr Object
        (
            [_expression:protected] => select  from sales_flat_order_item AS OI WHERE OI.order_id=main_table.entity_id
        )

)

Comment: Notice that the subquery's select clause is blank

Comment: nevermind, it was something else.  I am ashamed.

Comment: Don't be ashamed — everyone's wrong until they're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question doesn't have enough context to provide a concrete answer, so I'm going to explain why Magento is throwing an exception with the message

> Cannot determine the field name

Hopefully that will give you enough information to track down the problem.

In a stock Magento system, the **only** place the error "Cannot determine the field name" appears is

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Collection/Abstract.php
protected function _attributeToField($attribute)
{
    $field = false;
    if (is_string($attribute)) {
        $field = $attribute;
    } elseif ($attribute instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute) {
        $field = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    }
    if (!$field) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cannot determine the field name.'));
    }
    return $field;
}
```

So, if the `_attributeToField` method is passed an attribute value that's

1. An Empty string
2. An attribute object where `getAttributeCode` returns false (or one of the many values PHP considers false-ish)
3. Something that's not an `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute` or string

then the exception "Cannot determine the field name" is thrown.

In a standard system Magento calls this method when you call a collection object's `addAttributeToSelect`, `addAttributeToFilter`, `addAttributeToSort`, or `addAttributeToSearchFilter` methods.

So, something about your code causes an invalid value to be passed to `_attributeToField`.  This means the problem isn't your sub-query, or the sub-query may alter something that causes an invalid value to be passed.